# How to design menu kind of View IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I need to design a view in which I want to create a sub view which should show like menu in Android, When we click menu button in Android mobile, an vertical view will pop up(that occupy part of its parent view) and it will get focus.. same thing I need to design in IOS. Do I need to create a view and add as subview, or Is there anything we can do other than that? Please suggest me some ideas for that..

thanks.

Comment: dont try to make ios app looks like android app. also UIPopoverController may be what you want

Comment: @xlc0212 You are right.. What can we do? design is not in my hand? :)

Comment: UIPopover is only available on iPad though.

Comment: depends on the intended purpose of the menu. i suggest you to look Apple's Pages app. use UIPopoverController combined with UINavigationController + UITableViewController can do a good job

Comment: TableView can do the list and take you to another view to do other things (edit/view/ etc) when an individual row is touched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an semi-transparent UIView over your top view, on which you can place / design components as you wish, user interaction with anything below it won't be available, and you'll create the menu impression, because the user will be able to see the view below as well, even though it will be greyed out and non-usable, until you remove / hide the overlay view.

Comment: With this approach, be sure to add any other view behind your menu. This can occur if you create views asynchronously.

Comment: @vlad I got your point, but I am wondering, why apple is not providing anything particular for this kind of thing, as above people mentioned iPad they given UIPopover but not for other devices, we need to do all with UIView only????

Comment: Apple is providing this, by the means of UIActionSheet. Most if not all of the functionality done using menus is using UIActionSheet and as far as i know, it is the only available option. However, this is only suited if you wish to achieve a standard UI for the menu. Should you want something more custom, you gotta write your own UI control, as in the approach I've suggested above.

Comment: @Vlad UIActionSheet I have used in may places, I was expecting something like UIPopover for all devices... Anyhow thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score -1):

Support for menus was added in iOS 13 & more in iOS 14. See UIMenu.